# How to disable drag and drop of folders but not files in SharePoint online Document library?

Tags: drag-and-drop, sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am using **SharePoint online**. I have a requirement, in the **Document Library** users are **not allowed to drag and drop folders** but they **can drag and drop files**.
If a folder is dragged I need to show a warning.
How can we achieve this? I was trying with SPFx but had no luck. Can I add event listener to detect folder drop before it is dropped?.
Any suggestion to achieve this would be really helpful

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is achievable. You might want to have a look into this:

[How can I disable the Document Library drag and drop function?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82805/how-can-i-disable-the-document-library-drag-and-drop-function)

Also you can read this ms doc:

[Information about dragging files into document libraries in SharePoint Server 2013 or SharePoint Online by using a web browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/dragging-files-using-web-browser)